# SetInterval does not work when it is in another function?

Tags: javascript

When I put setInterval(autoAdmit, 1000) just below the autoAdmit() function, it works but when I place it in the if statements of another function, it does not work. Any ideas on why this is happening? I can't find anything that's wrong with it. forgot to mention: the part not working is the autoAdmit() function. When I put a console.log in the function, it still logs but what is inside the for loop is not executed for some reason.

```
let clickIntervalId = null;

function autoAdmit() {

  for (let element of document.getElementsByTagName('span')) {
    if (element.innerHTML === 'Admit') {
        console.log('There is someone waiting to join this meeting, automatically admitting them...');
        element.click();
    }
  } 

}
//setInterval(autoAdmit, 1000) (if it is placed here it works)

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var checkbox = document.querySelector('#auto-admit .mdc-switch__native-control');

  function isChecked() {
    if (checkbox.checked ) {
      // do this
      if(clickIntervalId) clearInterval(clickIntervalId);
        clickIntervalId = setInterval(autoAdmit, 1000); //(if it is placed here, it doesn't work)
        console.log('checked')
    } else {
      // do that
      clearInterval(clickIntervalId);
      console.log('not')
    }
  }
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
    isChecked();
  });

  function check() {
    isChecked();
  }
  setTimeout(check, 2000)
  

}

);
```

Comment: Are you certain the condition returns true for the `if` statement in the first place?

Comment: @un-index well when I test it with the setInterval below, it works and I change nothing between the tests so it does return true

Comment: un-index is not asking that. He is asking are you sure it prints 'checked' and not 'not'?

Comment: yes it does print "checked ", I use those to test... that's why I'm so confused on why it's not working. This is an extension for google meet, would it be easier if I linked github?

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS If you take a closer look at those questions, you'll see that the OP's code has none of those errors...

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS The titles of those were similar, but the underlying problems weren't. If you intended it as a thinking starter (I don't know how to say that better), then just prefix it with something like "*I don't know if these are related, but check them out*"...

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS Sorry, I didn't get that. What do you mean by that?